# Download a file from the FTP server: The remote server returned an error: (425) Can't open data connection

Tags: c#, ftp

Here is a function I have written to download a file from the FTP server. This works when I call this on the Desktop application or console application. But fails and gives the error message when this is in Windows Service or make a console application called from windows scheduler. I need to get a selected files daily. I am trying to automate instead of running manually every day morning.

```
private void GetFile(string url, string user, string pwd, string folder, string filename
                        , string destloc, string destfile)
{
        try
        {
            string RemoteFtpPath = url + folder + "/" + filename;
            String DestLoc = destloc + destfile;

            String Username = user; 
            String Password = pwd;  
            Boolean UseBinary = false; // use true for .zip file or false for a text file
            Boolean UsePassive = false;

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RemoteFtpPath);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.UsePassive = UsePassive;
            request.UseBinary = UseBinary;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            if (File.Exists(DestLoc))
                File.Delete(DestLoc);
            using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(DestLoc, FileMode.Create))
            {
                long length = response.ContentLength;
                int bufferSize = 2048;
                int readCount;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (readCount > 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like your Service Account and Task Scheduler User running your process do not have privileges to access the network.

Comment: Never do `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. You'll lose your stack trace. Just do `throw;` which will rethrow the caught exception, but maintain the stack trace. Also: your try/catch is providing you no benefit here. If you're not going to actually do anything in your catch block besides rethrow, then ditch the try/catch.

Comment: First thing I'd check is the permissions of the account the service/scheduled task runs as.

Comment: Does the service run on the same machine, where the code works in desktop/console application?

Answer (score 0):

By changing the properties solved the issue.

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = false;
```